# Nested list from two-dimensional Array

Tags: php, html, list, recursion, nested

I want to create a nested list in HTML (with ul and li) out of a two-dimensional array.

The array looks like this:

```
myArray["1"]["name"] -> Apple
myArray["1"]["parent"] -> 2
myArray["2"]["name"] -> Fruits
myArray["2"]["parent"] -> 3
myArray["3"]["name"] -> Food
myArray["3"]["parent"] -> (empty)
myArray["4"]["name"] -> Water
myArray["4"]["parent"] -> 5
myArray["5"]["name"] -> Drinks
myArray["5"]["parent"] -> (empty)
myArray["6"]["name"] -> Milk
myArray["6"]["parent"] -> 5
```

And now i want to find all these relations (also more layers) and dispaly them with HTML list elements:

```
    $allObjects = db_getAll();

    function r($parent, $arrayAllObjects){

        foreach ($arrayAllObjects as $object) {
            if ($object["parent"]==$parent) {
                return ("<ul>".$object["name"]."<li>". r($object["ID"], $arrayAllObjects)."</li></ul>");
            }
        }
    }


    echo r("0", $allObjects);
```

It starts good and the first "branch/arm" is displayed perfectly but after that (the first leaf at the end) it stops :(

Current Result:

```
 -Food
  -Fruits
   -Apple
```

Missing:

```
 -Drinks
  -Water
  -Milk
 -Example
  -Test
   -Test
   -...
 -...
```

What did I forget?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why are you not wrapping `$object["name"]` inside the `li` element? It's invalid html

Comment: because another layer might follow in that knot/"leaf" - thanks for correcting the html - sadly my problem is the recursion which breaks after the first ending leaf.

Comment: Can you create a more complex example with those layers you mentioned and the expected output vs. the actual output? Very hard to understand what is the expected output with only 2 elements

Comment: added one more layer and a new branch, hope that helps. (No matter how many layers, the first branch is correct but if he finds the first ending-item it stops)

Comment: Is is possible to change the structure of `$myArray`?

Comment: The current structure comes like that from our db_fetch - of course we can change it afterwards - how? (Until now we prefer npthin higher than two-dimensional - but open for every solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after processing the first item at the base layer, you then `return` inside the `foreach` loop which means that it won't go onto any further items.

Instead you need to build up all of the output and return this from the end of the function...

```
function extractLayer($parent, $arrayAllObjects){
    $output = "";
    foreach ($arrayAllObjects as $object) {
        if ($object["parent"]==$parent) {
            $subLayer = extractLayer($object["ID"], $arrayAllObjects);
            if ( !empty($subLayer) )    {
                $output .="<ul>".$object["name"].$subLayer."</ul>";
            }
            else    {
                $output .= "<li>".$object["name"]."</li>";
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

echo extractLayer("0", $allObjects);
```

I've also changed the function name as `r` isn't obvious.

Just updated this as each leaf was also building a list of it's own even if there were no sub layers.  So this checks for sub layers and if there aren't any, it just puts the item in `<li>` tags.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much. Only thing I had to change: `code` if ( !empty($subLayer) )    {
                $output .="**<li>".$object["name"]."<ul>".$subLayer."</ul></li>**";
            }
            `code` because <ul> isnt allowed (directly) inside an <ul>. Everything else was perfect. Thank you!